# Copy Rotation Constraint not working when paired with a Shrinkwrap

Tags: constraints

So my scene is a boat on an ocean modifier. I have a shrinkwrap modifier on a plane, the rough size of the boat, directly under it. Vertex group has been set. Plane is subdivided. Boat is not responding to rotations from the shrinkwrap, but is responding to the location.

I don't know. I might've set the origin point wrong or something? Don't really know how to fix it. Please help.

I'll leave a link to the .blend file below.

Thank you.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NmOY5HXwDEhCtLWLKaLXwPvyDrDjpvsz/view?usp=sharing

---

Ok, so apparently moving the plane with the shrinkwrap modifier fixes this, but why?

Comment: hello, your link asks for an authorization  ;)

Comment: What do you want to rotate so that the boat (?) rotates too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm always suspicious of copying rotation (or scale, or transforms) from vertices.  Why?  Because vertices don't have those characteristics.  What is a vertex group's rotation?  What is its scale?  Those aren't questions with clear answers.  Blender might try to *give* them those characteristics, for purposes of a constraint, but it's really weird that it does, and, for a few reasons, I'd expect poor behavior from Blender when trying to do that stuff-- not least, because it's not likely to get very intensive testing from users.

What would I do?  I would shrinkwrap two empties to the ocean, then damped track one and locked track the other:

[image]

Empties have been scaled up and changed to sphere display to improve visibility.  Shrinkwrap constraints on empties are not shown.